# TFS RESTORE ISSUE

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioeKw.jpg)

TFS ERROR WHILE RESTORING THE TFS

Comment: Did you read the KB article linked in the error message and follow the instructions?

Comment: Hi, I have cleared the issue as per the instructions thank you..,

Comment: Restoring has been completed successfully but my project collections not listed in new tfs console

Comment: Are there errors in the event viewer in your TFS server?

Comment: there is no error. successfully completed the restoring. how to get the restored project collections to the new console? please help

Answer (score 1):

After you restore database succeed. By restoring the databases that TFS uses, you have already restored the data tier of the original deployment. Now you must **complete the restoration process by installing the application tier (the application and services that compose Team Foundation Server) by using the Application-Tier Only wizard.**

To install the application tier and the extensions:

1. Open the administration console and start the configuration process.
   [image]
2. Launch the application-tier only wizard.
   [image]
3. Specify the name of the SQL Server where you just restored the
   databases and choose List Available Databases to populate the list.
   [image]
4. Provide the same service account information as used in the prior
   deployment, if possible.
   [image]
5. Complete the wizard.
   [image]

   ...

More detail steps, please kindly refer our official doc here--  [Install and configure Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-install-config-tfs?view=azure-devops)